# Dygraph on GWT with googlevizualization

Tags: gwt, dygraphs

I'm trying to use Dygraph on our GWT project. But,
I cannot find dygraph-gwt.jar f.e. from here http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2012/04/gwt-dygraph-example-using-visualization.html

Also I looked http://dygraphs.com/

I've already have some vizualization charts with data.

So, Can anybody show me example how to use Dygraph on GWT with GViz?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1-

You can browse through Dan's GitHub account for [DyGraph](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/tree/master/gwt). You do not need a jar as there is not much of GWT wrapper built around it. You can copy the files under gwt folder into your code base in the same package hierarchy as in Dan's Git repo and follow the rest from the [blog](http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2012/04/gwt-dygraph-example-using-visualization.html) as is .

### Solution 2-

1. There is a more recent gwt wrapper around dygraph by another developer @ https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs-gwt/
2. Dygraphs GWT Usage - https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs-gwt/wiki/ExampleUsage
3. Another Use Case via [UnitTest](https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs-gwt/source/browse/trunk/dygraphs-gwt-test/src/org/danvk/client/DygraphsGwtTest.java).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but unfourtinately I couldn't include it to my project. That brings me to use [Highcharts](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/download.jsp)

Comment: You can close this query by accepting the answer or You can upvote to indicate it helped. You can post your reason for choosing highchart for others who will stumbles across this query. We too use highcharts!!! It was nice to know about this alternative :)